# jquery simple onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="tab" href="#pictures">
   <i class="pink ace-icon fa fa-gift bigger-120"></i>
    Pictures
</a>
```

I want to wire on click #picture event to alert some message so I add

```
 $(document.ready(function() {
        $("#pictures").click(function(){
            alert('clicked!');               
        });
 })
```

but this doesnt work, I've got no error messages inside firebug console.
Jquery is loaded before correctly.

Comment: You want alert when element with id `"picture"` is clicked or the a href `"#pictures"` is clicked?

Comment: Do you want to wire event with `a href="#pictures"`?

Comment: Have you added jquery.min.js?

Comment: You have error in your js, it should be `$(document).ready(` missing closing parenthesis after document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your html there is no element with ID `pictures`, change it, like so

```js
$("#pictures").click(function(){
  alert('clicked!');               
});

// or use selector like this, if you can't change html
$('a[href="#pictures"').click(function(){
  alert('clicked!');               
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="tab" href="#pictures" id="pictures">
   <i class="pink ace-icon fa fa-gift bigger-120"></i>
    Pictures
</a>
```

**Update:**

Also you have error in this line

```
$(document.ready(function() {
```

change it

```
$(function() {
   // put your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did You try tout set the click handler on document?

```
jQuery(document).on('click',  '#pictures', function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
});
```

You also have to add :

```
id="pictures"
```

In your . Or an y other selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still use the #picture in href  check on bellow code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("a[href='#pictures']").click(function(){
         alert('clicked!');   
         return false;            
     });
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/nhLpnw7x/), even changed some markup for the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#pictures").click(function(){
            alert('clicked!');               
        });
 })
```